# file upload in google drive python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

How can I upload a file to a google drive with metadata part?
I have tried with the following method but I am getting the response,
"Request too large"  or "Metadata part too large"

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}

files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para),  'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open(path, "rb")
        }

response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: Can I ask you about ``para`` and the file size you want to upload?

Comment: file size upto `50 MB` and `para` include the `file name` and  `folder id `

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason of your issue is the file size. [The official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) says that ``Multipart upload: uploadType=multipart. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata describing the file, all in a single request.``. In order to upload the file with the size of more than 5 MB, please use Resumable upload. The document is [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable).

Comment: even after trying with that I am getting the request is too large error
`url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable'

para = {'name':'sample.ipa'}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'xxxx', 
    'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

files = {
 'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para)),
 'file': open('lp.ipa', "rb")
        }

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)`

Comment: @Tanaike can you pls suggest any alternate methods or modifications in this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you update your question including your current script? I think that it will help users think of about your issue. I think that [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) and [the threads on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google+resumable+upload+python) will be useful for you.